# Add session to class code

Tags: python, session

Original code is work fine:

```
class Sms:
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.key = api_key
        self.url = 'http://sms.com'

    def request(self, action):
        params = {**{'api_key': self.key}, **action.data}
        response = requests.get(self.url, params)
        return response.text
```

I need to add session to connect:
I do:

```
class Sms:
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.key = api_key
        self.url = 'http://sms.com'

    def get_tor_session():
        session = requests.session()
        # Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
        session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
                           'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
        return session

    def request(self, action, session=get_tor_session()):
        params = {**{'api_key': self.key}, **action.data}
        response = session.get(self.url, params)
        return response.text
```

But then i got error:

```
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

How to write right syntax?

Comment: `response = session.get(self.url, **params)`

Answer (score 1):

`get` only has one positional argument

```
get(url, **kwargs)
```

as described in the documentation http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#sessionapi. You will have to pass `params` via keyword arguments.

Comment: NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined

Comment: But why `response = requests.get(self.url, params)` works, instead of `response = session.get(self.url, params)` ?

Comment: Because `response.get` has the following signature: `requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)`. It takes two positional arguments, and optional ones must be passed as keyword arguments. Note that `params` can also be a keyword argument.

Comment: You are passing `params`, which is of type `dict`, as a positional argument. If you want to pass it as key-value pairs (which you should, since `session.get` only gets one positional argument) you need to unpack it with `**` (i.e. `**params`).

Comment: Then i got error `TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_key'`